# Undefined reference to Library android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working with android ndk and I got this error when build my project:

```
error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,         std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/khoa/ndk/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/khoa/Khoa/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(mathfuncs.cpp.o): in function cv::magnitude(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&):mathfuncs.cpp(.text._ZN2cv9magnitudeERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0x278): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/khoa/ndk/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/khoa/Khoa/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(mathfuncs.cpp.o): in function cv::magnitude(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&):mathfuncs.cpp(.text._ZN2cv9magnitudeERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_RKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0x2aa): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
```

In Application.mk i have added:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_STL := -lsupc++
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

This is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
include /home/khoa/Khoa/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
LOCAL_MODULE := csp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := csp.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How do I resolved this problem?

Comment: **APP_STL** shoul be chosen only once. I vote for **gnustl_static**. Please show your `Android.mk`.

Comment: @Alex Cohn: How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you rebuilt `libopencv_core.a` with different toolchain, you should use **gnustl_static**.

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
include /home/khoa/Khoa/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_MODULE := csp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := csp.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

See the [opecv documents](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html) for more details and actual screenshots that can help you set up your environment.

Don't hesitate to ask for details if something is not clear, or if this change does not resolve all build problems. If there is trouble, please post the build log created with `ndk-build V=1`.